# Testing each element in collection of collection only once

Tags: c++, c++11, optimization

I'm coding a CPU-raytracer for x86 consumer hardware (and in C++11, using gcc 4.7.1 so far).

I'm using a kD-tree holding my triangles and am intersecting all triangles in a leaf with my given ray. This task takes most of the runtime according to my profiler (depending on the kd-tree and input and chosen parameters about ~50% or more of my runtime).

```
for (auto p : leaf.triangles) {
    p->intersect(ray, t, intersection); //void intersect(const Ray& ray, float t, Intersection& output)
}
```

(p is of type pointer to an triangle somewhere else in a vector).

My kd tree may be expanded deeper, but that forces me to have more leafs sharing the same triangle. Because I'm often forced to test adjacent leafs I will end up intersecting the same triangles over and over again. This may be my greatest bottleneck so far.

A simple solution seemed some kind of list that would keep all the pointers I already intersected. I decided to use an `unordered_set<Triangle*>` because of its constant average cost for `find` and `emplace`.

```
unordered_set<Triangle*> alreadyTested; //used for all leafs a ray visits
for (auto p : leaf.triangles) {
     if (alreadyTested.find(p) == alreadyTested.end()) {
          p->intersect(ray, t, intersection);
          alreadyTested.emplace(p);
     }
}
```

compiled with GCC -O3

My runtime overall increased by a factor of 4 to 8. My profiler tells me that `find` and `emplace` take about the same time as a single `intersect` negating any speed bonus. Missed jump predictions may be the reason of the massive slowdown.

How do I do it right ("it" being calling intersect only once per triangle)?

Comment: Why not to use `std::vector<bool>` to store the "already tested" flag of `i`th triangle?

Comment: I have up to 7 digits of triangles and use all the cores I can get. Storing an explicit array / vector of bools would take megabytes per ray. Explicit flags seem not practical for those numbers.

Comment: `find` and `emplace` can be replaced with a single `insert` call: `auto x = alreadyTested.insert(p); if (x.second) x.first->intersect(ray, t, intersection);`.

Comment: Much more elegant, but not significantly faster (the internals seem to do nearly the same). Even with `-flto` it did not result in any speedup in my tests.

Answer (score 1):

You could keep counting rays and store the index of the last ray that you intersected a triangle against directly in the triangle. If you're multithreaded, you can have multiple such values and index by thread index.

`emplace` may take so much time due to re-hashing. You can use statistics collected from the last frame (for the same ray, or just an upper bound for all rays) to specify a better initial number of buckets to the `unordered_set` constructor.

Comment: I cannot use statistics from old frames (the program is suppossed to be a benchmark frame by frame), so I will retest with reasonable large bucket sizes.

Comment: The triangle solution seems smart, but it will inflate the size of each triangle (for example by the size of a vector containing these informations for all threads). Again, it seems to me that keeping track of ray indices explicitly would detriment performance, especially because you would need to guarantee uniqueness of every ray's index. A pointer may work as ID, so I will try that. A pure caller-side solution may still seem more practical (and potential better suited for cache efficiency).